# Micro Services with API Gateway - Ocelot vs Envoy

Tags: .net-core, envoyproxy, ocelot

I have a .NET core based micro service architecture and have several micro services. We chose ocelot as api gateway for routing, aggregation & security implementation. During our architectural discussion it was mentioned that Envoy Api Gateway is also a good option to use but couldn't find any differences between Ocelot & Envoy, it pros and cons like performance, scalability, community support etc...

Can any one help in sharing some insight on which one would be the good option to use for .NET Core applications.

Comment: [Ocelot is dead.](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/1539). Avoid it. Envoy is Go, so if your project is .NET you will have to learn new language if you need to customize it. Check the [YARP](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy) project, if you are looking for C# based Api Gateway supported by MS.

Comment: @Artur Envoy is not written in Go, but in C++ (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy). Otherwise, I agree with your comment. By the way, for the author, Envoy comes with a lot of features, a rich set of different filters, and a good community. You probably won't need to customize the code. YMMV, but I personally never had to fork it to adapt to my needs.

Comment: @norbjd yeah, you are right. I thought he is talking about [this project](https://github.com/envoyproxy/gateway). Anyway, when i'm talking about customization I mean writing plugins and so on. I'm not familiar with Envoy, but with YARP, you can write custom route provider, use authentication tools you are familiar from .NET ecosystem and many more. It might be more convinient chose for .NET developers.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input appreciate it. Do you guys recommend any other good API Gateways that I can use for .NET Core projects ?

Comment: As of July 2023, Ocelot has been updated with some commits within the last few months. Hence, I don't think it is dead.

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi agree, as we can see here https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Ocelot is being referenced in a lot of reliable sources. For example read this one. It is explaining the cons and pros too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/front-end-communication

Comment: You can use YARP too. A Microsoft backed reverse proxy. https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy